# Where do you usually install debug versions of libaries you build from sources?

Tags: c++, c, linux, debugging, build

Where do you usually install debug versions of libaries you build from sources, e.g. under /usr/local/debug, something else?

Consider a software library you use for your developing program. If you need to go into the library's source code under debugger, you need the library build without optimizations and with debug symbol generated. On the other hand, to normally run your application or estimate a performance you usually use 'release' build of the library, such builds are typically installed under /usr/local (default prefix).

thx

Comment: There's no usual repository used, or at least none that I'm aware of. I just create my own repository and add it to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: ^ this probably - I'm used to working on windows whene there even isn't sa standard layout for include/lib/bin so I made up my own, per project, and on unix I just do the same: pass custom directory/prefix to configure and done - *edit* it was expected this was going to get closed, don't really agree though esp. if the question is rephrased as 'is there a standard way to do this'

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard answer to this.

If we assume that `${project}` is the name of the relevant project - e.g `llvm` or `jpeglib` or whatever, then:

You can store the files locally in your home directory (`~/${project}/...`). I use the pattern `/usr/local/${project}-debug/...`  on my home machine. At work, I have my files in `/work/${project}/target-dir` - where `target-dir` is the name of the embedded platform I built it for - since my work involves building for a variety of different platforms, and I don't want to rebuild every time.

Of course, this also means that you have to modify the linker path to take this path ahead of the "normal" install directory. Not a big problem, just add a `-L~/${project}/lib` or whatever you decided on. And when you run things, you may need to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` to ensure the correct shared library files are picked up.